# Sending a file in jquery ajax POST Api call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Jquery, when i try to call external API by sending any file. I'm facing 415 Unsupported Media Type error. I'm trying to send my document using FormData() and header data in beforeSend() function. Suggest me correct way of sending data.

```html
<div id="folder-browser">
  <input type="file" id="file-select" name="photos" />
  <button id="myButton" value="click me">click me</button>
</div>
```

```js
$("#myButton").click(function() {
  var myData = new FormData();
  var myFile = document.getElementById("file-select");
  myData.append(myFile.files[0].name, myFile.files[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://10.96.45.179/RightFax/API/attachments',
    data: myData,
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic c3lzYWRtaW46cGFzc3dvcmQtMQ==');
    },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
       return result;
    }
  });
});
```

Query 2: If my document is present in URL. please let me know How can I pass the URL as a file source.
for Example:

```
filepath = 'http://seekvectorlogo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/opentext-vector-logo-small.png';
```

I need to pass this file source to my external API.

Comment: When uploading binary data in a `FormData` object you need to set `contentType: false`

Comment: Thanks! It resolved my error.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When uploading binary data in a FormData object you need to set `contentType: false`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://10.96.45.179/RightFax/API/attachments',
  data: myData,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  // your other settings...
});
```